# Sylius - 2 Backends?

Tags: sylius

I just installed Sylius and noticed that there are 2 backend sites. The installation documentation directed me to /admin. The site frontend has a link to /administrator. 
What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/admin is the original backend. /administrator is the new backend. See this article: http://sylius.org/blog/backend-redesign   
There are also some differences in how products are created. When I created products in the old backend, it generated an error when displaying the product list in the new backend. I went back to the old backend, deleted the products and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, /admin is the new one,

Have a look at the last security config file here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/app/config/security.yml

/administration is part of the SyliusWebBundle which is no more used (https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/5535)